# how to solve Adobe flash player security warning error

Tags: flash

successfully i created my movie using flash cs4 and i publish the file through flash 8 .In my application i had registration form .if i directly run the movie (cntrl + enter)it working fine and update the mysql db properly.But if i run the same movie by click the SWF file i get the following error pop up box

> ```
>  Adobe Flash Player has stopped a potentially unsafe operation
> ```
>
> The following local application on
>   your computer or network
>
> D:\new\copy.swf is trying to
>   communicate with this Internet-enabled
>   location: localhost
>
> To let this application communicate
>   with the internet , click Setting You
>   must restart the application after
>   changing your settings,

then i click the settings button ,it will automatically redirected me to the URL

> http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04a.html

In that page i did all the steps, but again and again  i receive the same error while i run the swf file please give some ideas how to set my swf file as trusted one .

Comment: Are you working on a Desktop AIR project?

Comment: Thank you for you time..., i solve the error i did mistake in the url. the url is - >  D:\new\copy of file.swf  but if i browse through the ADD Location link it take the URL like this D:\new\copy%20of%20file.swf  now i add the url manully now it works. thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want local access right you have to publish your SWF as an AIR project, or to run it from a webserver, not directly from the file system.

The reason while it works in the Flash IDE when pressing Ctrl+Enter is because in that case these security limitations are lifted to make it easier to test, but that's the exception not the rule :)

Comment: Thank you for you reply , could you please tell me how to i publish my file as AIR Project.

Comment: Sure, it's as simple as changing the target in Publish settings, for more info check out this video tutorial: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BZdEKqjLmhI

Comment: yeah, sand box while testing from the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make the SWF file trusted you can create a .cfg file with the path to the file or directory containing it, and place the file inside the local or global FlashPlayerTrust folder. You can read some info on Adobe's site, or googling around, eg: [here](http://muratsalma.com/en/blog/flashplayer-security-and-bypassing-swf-access-restrictions).

There are two things to take into account:

1. This must be done in user's computer.
2. This can be done only with local SWFs, not online.

Answer (score 0):

i was also looking to solve this issue as i also had it.
after fiddling with it for AGESS i came across this piece of code int he dreamweaver websitre source code (not in any scripts or anything ike that):

```
<param name="movie" value="../Flash/Flash1.swf" />
<param name="quality" value="high" />
<param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
<param name="swfversion" value="15.0.0.0" />
```

Then i look closer into

```
<param name="swfversion" value="15.0.0.0" />
```

Note the version 15?
i changed it to 11.0.0.0

EVERYTHING WORKED FINE FOR ME?
Does anyone know why. originally i thought i was flash version (mines is 11) hence why i changed it to 11.0.0.0 . but maybe it isnt

this is how is solved the issue anyway. let me know if it works for you

thanks